# Word Macro object variable or with block variable not set on alternate run

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have written a macro that would bring values of certain field from a word file and insert it in a excel file. On every alternate run the word macro gives an error "object variable or with block variable not set". Please help me.

```
Sub getWordFormData()
    Dim exApp As Object, myDoc As Object
    Dim myFolder As String, strFile As String
    Dim excelApp As Object
  Dim openExcel As Workbook

     myFolder = ActiveDocument.Path
        If Len((myFolder)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox myFolder & vbCrLf & "Not Found", vbInformation, "Cancelled - getWordFormData"
        End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set exApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set myDoc = ActiveWorkbook
   Set excelApp = New Excel.Application
  Set openExcel = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("F:\VBA Sample projects\word to excel\Proposal_DB.xlsx")
  excelApp.Visible = True
excelApp.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
   Set myDoc = exApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=myFolder & "\" & "TEMPLATE WORD.docx", ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
            With excelApp
             .Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value = myDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("date").Item(1).Range.Text
            .Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value = myDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("ProtocolNo.").Item(1).Range.Text
            .Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value = myDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("Subject").Item(1).Range.Text
            'excelApp.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 4).Value = myDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("companyname").Item(1).Range.Text
            'excelApp.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 5).Value = myDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("customer_name").Item(1).Range.Text
            'excelApp.Cells(Nextrow.Row, 6).Value = myDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("total_amount").Item(1).Range.Text
            'excelApp.Cells(Nextrow.Row, 7).Value = myDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("employee_name").Item(1).Range.Text
End With
            myDoc.Close SaveChanges:=False
           ' strFile = Dir()
        'Wend
        excelApp.Quit

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'End With
'exApp.Quit
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What line is highlighted if you hit Debug?

Comment: `Set myDoc = ActiveWorkbook` this will not run in Word VBA

Comment: I Have commented out the above line, However it doesn't help. On debugging it gives the error on line .Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value = myDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("date").Item(1).Range.Text  on every alternate run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiled but not tested:

```
'add a reference to the Microsoft Excel objectl ibary in your VBA project
Sub getWordFormData()

    Dim myDoc As Document
    Dim myFolder As String, strFile As String
    Dim excelApp As Excel.Application
    Dim excelWb As Excel.Workbook, rw As Excel.Range

    myFolder = ActiveDocument.Path
    If Len(myFolder) = 0 Then
        MsgBox myFolder & vbCrLf & " Not Found", vbInformation, "Cancelled - getWordFormData"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'create Excel application and open the workbook
    Set excelApp = New Excel.Application
    excelApp.Visible = True
    Set excelWb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open("F:\VBA Sample projects\word to excel\Proposal_DB.xlsx")

    'get the next empty row in the worksheet
    With excelWb.Sheets(1) '<< or use a specific sheet name
        Set rw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
    End With

    'you don't need a separate Word instance to open this document...
    Set myDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=myFolder & "\" & "TEMPLATE WORD.docx", _
                       ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
    rw.Cells(1).Value = myDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("date").Item(1).Range.Text
    rw.Cells(2).Value = myDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("ProtocolNo.").Item(1).Range.Text
    rw.Cells(3).Value = myDoc.SelectContentControlsByTag("Subject").Item(1).Range.Text

    myDoc.Close savechanges:=False

    excelWb.Close savechanges:=True

    excelApp.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, one more thing when I run the macro in office 365, the macro stops working at the point “Dim excelApp As Excel.Application”. can you help?

Comment: i guess i have not imported the excel object library let me try and check